# .htaccess for multilangual website building

Tags: php, .htaccess

I edit my question basically I want below redirects if possible.

**and some notes**

- all urls should redirect **from http** to **secure https** version
- all urls should redirect from **www** version to **not www**
- Also we can't describle **tag,article or category in htaccess** cause it changes with language ***like category in english*** and **catégorie in french** but i controll this in my database..

| users request | in url shown | gives parameter to php not in url shown | what does htaccess |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| example.com/en | example.com | lang=en | page=home | deleting en from url and gives parameters background so i can use $_GET[] |
| example.com/en/contact | example.com/contact | lang=en | page=contact | deleting en from url and gives parameters background so i can use $_GET[] |
| example.com/fr/category/dental | example.com/fr/category/dental | lang=fr | page=category | parameter=dental |
| example.com/it/tag/flowers/ | example.com/it/tag/flowers | lang=it | page=tag | parameter=flowers |
| example.com/fr | example.com/fr | lang=fr | page=home | only define parameters in backgrounds to get $_GET[] |
| example.com/it | example.com/it | lang=it | page=home | only define parameters in backgrounds to get $_GET[] |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not feel like a sane solution, but I think it does what you have asked for.

```
RewriteEngine On

# https and non-www redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

# If lang en at start of uri, remove it
RewriteRule ^(en)$ / [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(en)(/.*)$ $2 [R,L]

# home page rewrites
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?lang=en&page=home [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})$ index.php?lang=$1&page=home [QSA,L]

# other page rewrites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?lang=en&page=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]

# other page with param rewrites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?lang=en&page=$1&parameter=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&parameter=$3 [QSA,L]

# fallback
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have used `([a-z]{2})` for the two character language pattern, but you can change it to the fixed group of options if you prefer - `(fr|tr|it)`.

`https://example.com/en`:

- 1st redirect: https://example.com/
- Rewrite (internal): index.php?lang=en&page=home

`http://www.example.com/en/category/dental`:

- 1st redirect: https://example.com/en/category/dental
- 2nd redirect: https://example.com/category/dental
- Rewrite (internal): index.php?lang=en&page=category&parameter=dental

`https://example.com/it/tag/flowers`:

- Rewrite (internal): index.php?lang=it&page=tag&parameter=flowers

Comment: With no visibility of your application, I have no idea how it is structured (or works), so it is not really possible to comment. The `RewriteCond` conditions check for the existence of a file or directory, if neither exists it attempts the `RewriteRule`. If the file/dir exists it will call it. It would be much easier to handle this with some basic routing code within your application.

Comment: _"But it just cross."_? I have no idea what you mean. I cannot see your application. None of the scripts/pages that you are including/requiring should be directly routable within the document root of your website. Normally, you would set the document root to a directory containing your "index.php" and all the static assets (js, css, images, etc) that need to be directly accessible. Everything else should be outside of the document root.

Comment: Glad you got there in the end.